# CSS Relative positioning overflow (squashed div problem) divs height expand with content?

Tags: css, height, css-position

I'm trying to edit some css to include a border to the right and the left of my site. My problem is that when I make my height 100% or auto nothing happens, but when I change the height it works, but I can't use this as I want it to change with the content.

I've noticed in expression web my sitegrinder div looks too squashed up the top instead of the full length of the content. Could this be due to positioning? Could overflow fix this somehow?

I have included the css and html below

```
  <div  id="sitegrinder">
    <div id="bgrepeat">
           <div id="id68logo"></div>
                  <div id="bglight"></div>
                        <div id="topbanner"></div>
                               <div id="id53light"></div>


#sitegrinder  {
left: auto;
top:auto;
width: 960px;
position: relative;
margin:auto;  }
```

I've also noticed that when I include overflow:hidden within the css all my content appears squashed at the top within this div.

Comment: If you can provide a link to a demo page, and/or an image showing how you'd prefer it to look, it might make it easier to offer advice. Also, it might be worth posting on http://doctype.com/ (for more purely html/layout support).

Comment: doctype.com is closing in Feb 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to make a horizontally centered div with a fixed with and graphics as left and right borders you should use something like this:

html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        ...your content here...
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#wrapper { width:980px; margin:0 auto;)
#content { margin:0 20; background transparen url(background_image.png) top center repeat-y; }
```

The background_image.png should be an image with 980px width. The 10 leftmost pixel.. and the 10 rightmost pixel are your border u can style the way you want.

Comment: Thanks Ricebowl I tried this but it didn't work. I think its because my main div is relatively positioned and the elements inside it are absolute. Not sure how too get round this?

Comment: its hard to answer your question without seeing your whole code.
my example would replace your first 2 divs.. so you should delete the first two divs (sitegrinder && bgrepeat) and put the other divs inside my content-div

if you could post a link to an example page i could give better help